# How to load all entities in doctrine2 when one is loaded via a relationship?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have several entities defined in doctrine ORM that are used as a category tree structure. In most cases when a single one of these is loaded its parent and children will need to be loaded as well. I have a repository that loads the entire tree structure when fetching a category directly but when the category is loaded via an association on an entity doctrine, of course, only loads the specific category. I'd like to be able to make doctrine load the entire tree when it fetches any category. (This is especially useful since the repository makes use of Doctrine's result cache)

For instance, say I have an entity of type `Size` that is my category tree. I have a `Book` entity that has an association to `Size`. When I get the `Book`'s size I want doctrine to call my repository method which will load all the sizes into memory rather than loading the individual size directly from the DB. I can get close to this behavior by adding a PostLoad event listener that loads all the categories after loading any one size but I'd like to get rid of the unnecessary DB call.

In short, is there some way of implementing a "PreLoad" event in doctrine 2 ORM?